# Recognizing a Missed Call on BlackBerry 10

Tags: call, blackberry-10

Regarding:

[http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb_*system*_phone__calltype.html](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__phone__calltype.html)

Anyone know why I can't get the "Missed" call type to work on the callUpdated slot?

```
  if (bb::system::Phone::CallType::Missed == call.callType()){
             missedLed->setColor(bb::device::LedColor::Yellow);
             missedLed->flash();

             }
```

doesn't work
but

```
if (bb::system::Phone::CallType::Incoming == call.callType()){
             missedLed->setColor(bb::device::LedColor::Yellow);
             missedLed->flash();}
```

and

```
   if (bb::system::Phone::CallType::Outgoing == call.callType()){
             missedLed->setColor(bb::device::LedColor::Yellow);
             missedLed->flash();

             }
```

works

Why?

I have all the pro file, hpp stuff, permission etc in there. So those aren't the problem.